# Terms query in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

What is the difference between terms and term set query?
How I can OR the query in term parameter?

For example:

```
GET /_serarch
{
    "Query":{
        "term":{"user":"kimchy"},{"Age": 25}
    }
}
```

Comment: Added code tags, prettied up the object indentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Terms Set Query you can provide an array of terms to match any of them in the document.

```
GET /my-index/_search
{
   "query": {
      "terms_set": {
          "codes" : {
              "terms" : ["abc", "def", "ghi"],
              "minimum_should_match_field": "required_matches"
          }
      }
   }
}
```

The term query finds documents that contain the exact term specified.

```
POST _search
{
  "query": {
  "term" : { "user" : "Kimchy" } 
  }
}
```

You can do OR using the bool query.

```
"query": {
  "bool" : {     
    "should" : [
      { "term" : { "tag" : "wow" } },
      { "term" : { "tag" : "elasticsearch" } }
    ],
    "minimum_should_match" : 1,
  }
}
```

}

Comment: In the example of terms_set you specify that you want to match any document that has a 'codes' property  that match any value of the array ["abc", "def", "ghi"] in the terms. Unlike term query where you match only one value.

Comment: Ok... Thank you so much! And there is way to Use OR in terms parameter instead of using bool queries???

Comment: you can use query_string if you want. [query_string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html)